# Exception while running a Spring MVC Hello World Example:org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException

Tags: spring-mvc

I tried to start the development on Spring MVC, just a little project, but getting the following exception :

**Cannot find class [controller.HelloController] for bean with name '/hello.ds' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/helloWorld-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controller.HelloController**

(My HelloController.java class is under src->controller package)

This is my **index.jsp**

```
<h1>HelloWorld</h1> 
<form action="./hello.ds"> 
Name:<input type="text" name="name"> 
<input type="submit" value="sayHello"> 
</form>
```

This is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 
<display-name>MVC First Project</display-name> 
<welcome-file-list> 
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list> 
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>helloWorld</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>helloWorld</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>*.ds</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

This is my **helloWorld-servlet.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" 
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd"> 
<beans> 
<bean name="/hello.ds" class="controller.HelloController"></bean> 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
<property name="prefix" value="/"></property> 
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property> 
</bean> 
</beans>
```

This is my controller:**Hello Controller.java**

```
package controller; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller; 
public class HelloController implements Controller { 
@Override 
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, 
HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
String name=req.getParameter("name"); 
Map m=new HashMap(); 
m.put("msg","hello.." +name); 
ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("success",m); 
return mav; 
} 
}
```

This is my **success.jsp**

```
${msg}
```

jars added:

```
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1 
com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15 
jmxtools-1.2.1 
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A 
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A 
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A 
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A 
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A 
org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A 
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A
```